# How to pass Class/Object from NODE-EJS to template?

Tags: node.js, ejs

New to EJS, and tried to search for solutions, but couldn't find example. Basically, I have a large class (object) with dozens of methods & properties, which I want to pass to template. I tried:

app.js

```
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.render(__dirname + '/index.html', {
        helpers: helpers, 
    }); 
});
```

index.html

```
...
...
<script>
    const helpers = <% helpers %>;
    helpers.method_1();
    ...
    helpers.method_2();
    ...
    helpers.method_3();
    // dozens of methods I have to use here. 
</script>
...
...
```

However, the object is not being passed normally (transformed to [Object object] ). What is the way to achieve exactly that?

---

btw, declaring methods one-by-one is no-way a solution.

Comment: Why not include the script via [static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) ?

Comment: @slideshowp2 please post answer, I will upvote it

Comment: @slideshowp2 the reason is that, `helpers` could theoretically be an object (with some methods) created inside app, so without any static file/location.